# Why I am having ValueError in this Linear Regression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

ClosePrices = data['Close'].tolist()
OpenPrices = data['Open'].tolist()


OpenPrices = np.reshape(OpenPrices, (len(OpenPrices), 1))
ClosePrices = np.reshape(ClosePrices, (len(ClosePrices), 1))

regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(OpenPrices, ClosePrices)
```

I am having the error

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

What is the solution?

Comment: Where exactly does the error occur? In `fit`? In the plots? Please post the full error trace. DId you check your input data for `NaN`, as the message advises?

Comment: in ```regressor.fit(OpenPrices, ClosePrices)``` this line.

Comment: Then you should not include the code *after* this line, since it is irrelevant to the issue (is never executed) and just creates unnecessary noise (edited & removed).

Comment: eidted. Now what can I do?

Comment: Is `LinearRegression()` from `sklearn.linear_model`?

Comment: yes this is from ```sklearn.linear_model```

Comment: Alright, what does the data look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dataset most likely contains missing (NaN) values. To be sure about the error, it would help a lot if you can show us the dataset you are using for the regression.

Answer (score 2):

There are most likely missing values in your data, those missing values are encoded as `NaN`.

The most common solutions for missing data are:

1. Drop the instances/rows that have any missing values.
2. [Impute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imputation_(statistics)) the missing values.